# Running mac osx commands from cronjob

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, cron

I've a cronjob (takes a screenshot every 10 minutes) in my macbook with mac osx El Capitan that excecutes the follow command:

```
*/10 * * * * cd /Users/userx/Pictures/memes && ./shared.sh
```

The shared.sh script contains the follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
_now=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S")
screencapture -x $_now.png
```

But when the system executes the cronjob I'm getting this error:

```
./shared.sh: line 3: screencapture: command not found
```

But if I run the shared.sh file directly in the terminal all is executed correctly.

Any ideas?? Can we run mac osx commands from cronjobs??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`screencapture` is in /usr/sbin, but the default PATH for cron jobs is just `/usr/bin:/bin` so it isn't found. There are several ways to solve this:

- Use the full path in the script (i.e. `/usr/sbin/screencapture -x $_now.png`).
- Set PATH in the script before using `screencapture` (i.e. `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`).
- Set PATH in the crontab before the entry for your script (syntax is the same as in the script).

Comment: thanks!, I use `/usr/sbin/screencapture -x $_now.png` and works fine :)